# Else statement repeating itself?

Tags: c++, if-statement, adventure

I'm working on a text adventure for a final project and I have a lot of If statements that check for if you type something like *"look lantern"*, then it will display information about it, etc.

I wanted to make it so if you typed something like *"srjfdrszdgrf"* it would just tell you "You can't do that." With an `else` statement at the bottom but it doesn't seem to work properly, instead it repeats the `else` statement after every `if`.
Am I doing something wrong?

```
if (command == "look_lantern")
{
    cout << "It's an ordinary lantern.\n";
}
if (command == "look_door")
{
    cout << "It's a large wooden door.\n";
}
else
{
    cout << "You can't do that.\n";
}
```

So when you type *"look lantern"* it says:

> It's an ordinary lantern.
>   You can't do that.

Am I using the `else` statement incorrectly here?

Comment: Did you edit this to add the missing `else` after posting? It seems a lot of answerers didn't see it there.

Comment: Works fine [here](http://ideone.com/hYkpr).

Comment: Yup, I forgot to use Else If, answered my own question. Thanks!

Comment: @Hydlide Off topic to your problem, but if you're interested in writing text adventures check out http://inform7.com/

Comment: Cool, I'll check it out!

Comment: @Hydlide Also, instead of editing your question to say resolved, check the correct answer given below as 'Accepted' (the check-mark.)

Comment: I just removed the fix. Otherwise the question makes no sense at all and makes the answers look wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you have two blocks, the first one:

```
if (command == "look_lantern")
{
    cout << "It's an ordinary lantern.\n";
}
```

and the second one:

```
if (command == "look_door")
{
    cout << "It's a large wooden door.\n";
}
else
{
    cout << "You can't do that.\n";
}
```

If you wanted only one block to execute you'd need to make the second block execute only if the firs one fails:

```
if (command == "look_lantern")
{
    cout << "It's an ordinary lantern.\n";
} else if (command == "look_door")
{
    cout << "It's a large wooden door.\n";
}
else
{
    cout << "You can't do that.\n";
}
```

Both of these get executed because there's nothing stopping execution after the first one.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you should use `else if`

```
if (command == "look_lantern")
{
    cout << "It's an ordinary lantern.\n";
}
else if (command == "look_door")
{
    cout << "It's a large wooden door.\n";
}
else
{
    cout << "You can't do that.\n";
}
```

If you wrote your code the old way, the first if will be executed, and output: "It's an ordinary lantern."

after that, the second `if` will be executed, and it does not match, so, the `else` branch is executed, outputing: "You can't do that."